# how event use click cancel row edit btn inline edit in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

15.2-pre .i want when click cancel row edit btn inline edit in row grid show event or call function  for show mesasge .but when click Does not do anything.
plase see demo [demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/207/)

```
     $('div[id^="jCancelButton"]').click(function () {
         alert('test')
         checkCrudGrid();
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question then you can use `afterRestore` callback of `actionsNavOptions`

```js
actionsNavOptions: {
    afterRestore: function (rowid) {
        alert("editing of the row with rowid=" +
              rowid + " is canceled");
    }
}
```

or `jqGridInlineAfterRestoreRow` event handler. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/322/.

Additionally I'd recommend you don't use any old "-pre" versions. The version "15.2-pre" is some version after an official version 15.1. Moreover, one have to specify the date of "-pre" version. For example, the current code on GitHub today have the version number "jqGrid 4.15.5-pre" and "Date: 2018-04-21". If I would make some changes in the code then I would change the date to "Date: 2018-05-06" *without* changing the name of preliminary version "4.15.5-pre". After publishing the new version it will be "4.15.5". During the next changes after the release I will change the version to the next "-pre" version - "4.15.6-pre" or "4.16.0-pre".

Comment: tahnks @Oleg  how check  btn save row whats event?

Comment: @saeeda: You are welcome! One can use `afterSave` callback inside of `actionsNavOptions`. One can use any other options or callbacks described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.4/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L671-L697). The names come from the options of `formatter: "actions"` (see old jqGrid documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types)).